# what happens while type casting to a different data type

Tags: c

why is the output fffffffa rather than 0000000a for this code

```
char c=0Xaa;
     int b=(int)c;
     b=b>>4;
     printf("%x",b);
```

what i thought was char c=OXaa will be aa and when it is typecasted to int it changes to 000000aa.

can anyone tell me what is happening when the char is being typecasted to integer..

Comment: Already your assignment of a value larger than 127 to a `char` may lead to undefined behavior. Don't do that, but always assign `'a'` type constants to plain `char`. To have an hexadecimal value in there you may use `'\xaa'` as in your example, but there are more chances that the compiler will tell you when you exceed the bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is signed so the upcast is sign-extending. Consider the binary representations.

`0xAA = 10101010`

`char` is often signed, so when you cast to the (signed by default) `int`, the first `1` means that it's interpreted as a negative twos-complement number:

```
((int) ((signed char)0xAA) ) = 11111111111111111111111110101010
```

To avoid this, use an `unsigned char` or an `unsigned int`.

Comment: thank you robert, so if char c=Ox77 (the leasing bit is 0). So does this provide 00000077 (hex) when type casted to int?

Comment: Yes, it should. But if you don't want sign-extension, you should really make that explicit using an `unsigned` type.

Comment: ok thank you very much robert. your explanation helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `char` type of your compiler is signed, so when it's converted to `int` it is sign-extended since the highest bit is set.

Then, the right-shift operator maintains the negative-ness, and shifts in new ones at the top. Right-shifting a negative value is an undefined operation, so don't do this.

Comment: `printf("%x\n", c); -> c=ffffffaa`.

Comment: thank you unwind. so char c=OX77, i.e 01110111. Now when this is typecasted to int and right shifted does it become 00000007 (hex) ? If so wat i perceived from your comment was correct

Comment: right-shifting `>>` a negative value is implementation defined behaviour; left-shifting `<<` a negative value is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pmg - left-shifting a negative value is the same as left-shifting a positive value, isn't it? And right-shifting a signed value usually performs sign extension, but not on an unsigned. Just another argument for using the right types!

Comment: @Robert: look at 6.5.7 in [the lastest publically available version of the standard (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @pmg - well fwiw, recent versions of GCC on Linux will do the arithmatic right shift when confronted with a negative signed number.

Comment: yep ... and [left-shifting, in GCC, is never undefined](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation).

Answer (score 0):

This is dependant on the architecture used (CPU) as well as the compiler.

In your case, my guess is that the value of variable c is placed in a cpu register, where only the lower 8 bits is defined. When casted to int and copied to another variable then those bits with "undefined" value gets copied too, and since they now are part of a integer value, are treated as valid.

To overcome this, you may want to copy the c value like this:

```
int b = (int)c & 0xff;
```

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the sign issue mentioned by unwind. So, his answer is more accurate in this example. In other situations though, it is good to be aware of the effects of type casting a value to a bigger type.